# Work out the integer values for which $x^{2} - 20x + 96 < 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Work out the integer values for which $x^{2} - 20x + 96 < 0.$

How should I approach the above question?

Comment: Do you know how to first work out the real values for which $x^2 - 20x + 96 < 0$?

Comment: I think it's using factorisation, but can't be sure. Then out of the two values should I just pick the negative one?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: Search the web for tutorials on "solving quadratic inequalities". Here's just one that I picked off of wikipedia: http://www.wtamu.edu/academic/anns/mps/math/mathlab/col_algebra/col_alg_tut23_quadineq.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $x^2-20x+96<0$ if and only if $(x-12)(x-8)<0$, so the values of $x$ are $8<x<12$; that is, for $x=9, 10, 11$.

Comment: Oh right, I get it. You see I thought it meant that the x needs to be positive but it makes sense that that's not the case.

Answer (score 3):

Hint : Find the solutions of the quadratic equation. Since the leading coefficient is positive, the function is negative between the roots. All the integers between the roots (without the roots itself) are solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by a) Leading Coefficient and b) Negative between the roots ?

Comment: The leading coefficient is the coefficient belonging to the largest exponent (here, it is $1$). With "between the roots" I mean the open interval $(a,b)$, if $a$ and $b$ are the roots.

Comment: $x^2 - 20x + 96 \lt 0$ ; Completing the square: $(x - 10)^2 - 4 \lt 0$; or $(x - 10)^2 \lt 4$; Implies for integer values of x: (x -10) = 0,1,-1. Hence x =9,10,11.